# Select the latest rows and then randomize those rows and then display the first 2 of the randomized rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, random, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called `student_grades`

```
╔════╤═══════╤═══════╤═════════════════════╗
║ id │ name  │ grade │ date_added          ║
╠════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╣
║ 1  │ bob   │ 23    │ 2019-10-01 14:25:00 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 2  │ james │ 45    │ 2019-10-02 17:31:27 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 3  │ mike  │ 42    │ 2019-10-03 18:08:13 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 4  │ bob   │ 68    │ 2019-10-04 02:00:00 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 5  │ mike  │ 83    │ 2019-10-04 09:28:43 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 6  │ bob   │ 23    │ 2019-10-04 11:42:00 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 7  │ james │ 86    │ 2019-10-05 12:11:20 ║
╚════╧═══════╧═══════╧═════════════════════╝
```

First I want to select all the names from the table BUT I only want their most recent record. For example. `James` has 2 records. One with `id 2` AND ONE WITH `id 7`. So I want the one with `id 7` because the id is larger.

So to do that I get:

```
╔════╤═══════╤═══════╤═════════════════════╗
║ id │ name  │ grade │ date_added          ║
╠════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╣
║ 5  │ mike  │ 83    │ 2019-10-04 09:28:43 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 6  │ bob   │ 23    │ 2019-10-04 11:42:00 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 7  │ james │ 86    │ 2019-10-05 12:11:20 ║
╚════╧═══════╧═══════╧═════════════════════╝
```

.

```
SELECT *
FROM student_grade 
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Now I want to randomize those rows and get the first 2 rows of those randomized rows

```
╔════╤═══════╤═══════╤═════════════════════╗
║ id │ name  │ grade │ date_added          ║
╠════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════════════════════╣
║ 7  │ james │ 86    │ 2019-10-05 12:11:20 ║
╟────┼───────┼───────┼─────────────────────╢
║ 5  │ mike  │ 83    │ 2019-10-04 09:28:43 ║
╚════╧═══════╧═══════╧═════════════════════╝
```

How do I randomize those 3 rows. My end goal is to get the latest records of each student. I don't care about their past records. I just want their most recent ones, and then I want to randomize them. What is the most efficient way of me doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. It finds the row for each student which has the maximum `id` value, and then sorts all those rows randomly and selects 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM student_grade s
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM student_grade
            WHERE name = s.name)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

Dependent on the size of your table, it may be more efficient to implement this as a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM student_grade s1
JOIN (SELECT name, MAX(id) AS id
      FROM student_grade
      GROUP BY name) s2 ON s2.name = s1.name AND s2.id = s1.id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bP2Yya7Vs1kTV5HmvwRuwA/1)

Comment: Would this be the most efficient way though?

Comment: Also I don't understand this line `WHERE name = s.name` What is the point of this line?

Comment: @Mick dependent on the size of the table, a JOIN might be more efficient. See my edit.

Comment: @Mick `WHERE name = s.name` ensures that the `MAX(id)` value returned by the subquery correlates to the `name` value from the current row of the output